# Get public_profile from messenger api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there any way how to get *public_profile* information from messenger api? I need just first name of the user.

I have tried `GET https://graph.facebook.com/<PSID>?fields=first_name&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/), but it only works for me and my page. For other users I got error:

> (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."

Do I need to request *Business Asset User Profile Access*? Is *public_profile* completely useless for messenger bot?

I am totally lost in FB doc and all other information I found is too old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need Business Asset User Profile Access.

There is a notice on the page which you linked to:
"To retrieve a user’s profile information, you need to have Advanced Access for the Business Asset User Profile Access feature."

:)